# PHP __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object

Tags: php, object

I have an object inside $_SESSION. When I try to modify the object I get __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']->lang = $_GET['lang'];
```

Comment: Try getting more clarity here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010427/php-php-incomplete-class-object-with-my-session-data

Comment: Having objects inside of sessions is almost always never a good idea.

Comment: I just don't get how I could change my lang var... @Allendar

Comment: We understand that you get that. But what is your question?

Comment: How can I change my lang var? @hakre

Comment: You do it this way: before starting the session load the class definition of the user object in that session. Then start the session and you can easily set it like you already do in the code. You're only missing to load the class definition before starting the session.

Comment: setting up an autoloader is a good way to avoid this as well.

Comment: YOU ARE A MASTER @hakre

Answer (score 1):

Its very likely that there is an object in the serialised session, but the system hasn't seen the class definition. 'require'ing it should allow it to be properly built.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a tip: Enable notices in your error reporting when you are developing and debugging issues. PHP tells you about problems. To give you an example of that I tried to reproduce your issue and create a class name `User` that is missing when unserializing:

> Notice: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "User" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

As you can see such a method already tells you which concrete class definition is missing and potential ways to solve the issue.