# php var_dump shows array but can't access it

Tags: php, arrays

Can't access array but `var_dump()` sees it.

```
session_start();

include './entities/Answer.php';
include './entities/Question.php';
include './Database.php';

 if (isset($_SESSION["question"])) {
        $correct = TRUE;
        var_dump($_SESSION["question"]);
        var_dump($_SESSION["question"]->answers);
        }
    } else {
        echo "<h2>no question selected.</h2>";
    }
```

`var_dump($_SESSION["question"]);`
shows:

```
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#2 (8) {  
    ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(8) "Question"  
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["correct"]=> NULL 
    ["wrong"]=> NULL 
    ["answers"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#3 (5) { 
            ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(6) "Answer" 
            ["correct"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["question_id":"Answer":private]=> NULL 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["text"]=> string(9) "antwort 1" 
        } 
        [1]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#4 (5) { 
            ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(6) "Answer" 
            ["correct"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["question_id":"Answer":private]=> NULL 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["text"]=> string(5) "ant 2" 
        }
        [2]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#5 (5) { 
            ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(6) "Answer" 
            ["correct"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["question_id":"Answer":private]=> NULL 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
            ["text"]=> string(5) "ant 3"
        }
    }
    ["creator_id"]=> NULL 
    ["categories"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["text"]=> string(17) "eine Test frage ?" 
}
```

but `var_dump($_SESSION["question"]->answers);` shows `NULL`.

I don't really understand that.

I got this as error message:

> PHP Notice:  main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Question" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably haven't included your class definition.

Comment: include './entities/Answer.php'; Answer is the type of the array

Comment: Swap `include` for `require` temporarily to ensure they are pulling in the desired code.  And check for errors.

Comment: i gave it a try but nothing changed, and i added a the error message.

Comment: Try placing session_start after your class definitions.

Comment: That solved it. I am glade and surprised. Thank you.

Comment: Follow the suggestion in the notice of using an autoloader instead of include statements for class definition imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to place session_start after my class definitions. Thanks to  [Progrock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3392762/progrock)

```
    include './entities/Answer.php';
    include './entities/Question.php';
    include './Database.php';

    session_start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `session_start()` before you try to interact with the session object.

Also, you need to define your object before you call session_start(), or else the PHP's session handler won't know how to deserialise the object.  That's why you see `__PHP_Incomplete_Class`.

EDIT: I found this answer that may help you [PHP __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object with my $_SESSION data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010427/php-php-incomplete-class-object-with-my-session-data)

Comment: Surely the session has been started, else $_SESSION likely empty.

Comment: i did that i just left it in the snippet.