# Wordpress site: Page reloading (with changed get-param) calls the strange behaviour

Tags: php, wordpress, session, wordpress-plugin-creation

**For moderators: My post not the same and not answered by [PHP __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object with my $_SESSION data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010427/php-php-incomplete-class-object-with-my-session-data), really! Because sessions is my finale attempt to solve the problem, before I used singleton class, wp_get_user etc. Please, don't close my question, it has more nuances!**

A plugin is being developed for a Wordpress site. Also on the site added authorization by oAuth through Google and Facebook (using the plugin miniOrange). I specify this point, because it may be significant.

So, a user with a certain Visitor role authorizes on the site via Google, and this is intercepted by the hook:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_login_handler', 20);
```

```
function custom_login_handler()
    {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('pickinteri_Visitor')) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $tmp_session = $_SESSION;
        Auth::visitorAuthSet($user->ID);
        $_SESSION['current_visitor'] = Pcab_Visitor::get_visitor();
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->ID = $user->ID;
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->first_name = isset($tmp_session['first_name'])?$tmp_session['first_name']:'';
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->last_name = isset($tmp_session['last_name'])?$tmp_session['last_name']:'';
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->full_name = isset($tmp_session['user_full_name'])?$tmp_session['user_full_name']:'';
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->display_name = isset($tmp_session['display_name'])?$tmp_session['display_name']:'';
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->email = isset($tmp_session['user_email'])?$tmp_session['user_email']:'';
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->avatar_url = isset($tmp_session['user_picture'])?$tmp_session['user_picture']:'';
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->social_user_id = isset($tmp_session['social_user_id'])?$tmp_session['social_user_id']:'';
        $_SESSION['current_visitor']->social_app = isset($tmp_session['social_app_name'])?$tmp_session['social_app_name']:'';
        if ($_SESSION['current_visitor']->display_name == '') {
            $_SESSION['current_visitor']->display_name = $user->display_name;
        }

    }
}
```

*Remark FYI* - `Pcab_Visitor::get_visitor()` is a singleton pattern class, so it doesn't have any `$var = new Pcab_Visitor()`.

and then from another hook

```
add_action('admin_init', 'redirect_dashboard');
```

```
function redirect_dashboard() {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('pickinteri_Visitor')) {
        wp_redirect(Auth::visitorCabinetURL());
        exit;
    }
    if (is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('subscriber')) {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
```

is redirected to the page https://domain.space/visitor-cabinet/

This page has its own menu (as well as with the cabinets of other roles, but there users are completely independent of the authorization system Wordpress - that's why I emphasized it at first), and, for example, I call the page of the same cabinet - but not by redirect, but by clicking in the menu https://domain.space/visitor-cabinet/?mode=settings.

That was a description of the process, and **now the actual problem** with the $current_visitor variable located in the visitor-cabinet.php script (which generates the specified pages).

In the first case it reports about itself (`var_dump()` output):

```
php_class: TCAby\PickinteriCabinet\Admin\Pcab_Visitor, php_object: TCAby\PickinteriCabinet\Admin\Pcab_Visitor::__set_state(array(
      'properties' => 
      array (
        'ID' => 12,
        'first_name' => 'Don',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'full_name' => 'Don Smith',
        'display_name' => 'Don Smith',
        'email' => 'mail@gmail.com',
        'avatar_url' => 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocJs_EdNxyyNf-lqA1WqY8xR-q-9ZX4jOdrd2NDY3Fz9Pp7p=s96-c',
        'social_user_id' => '1144905419045954546685675134657',
        'social_app' => 'google',
      ),
))
```

and the second time (the page with the get-parameter) is:

```
php_class: __PHP_Incomplete_Class, php_object: __PHP_Incomplete_Class::__set_state(array(
   '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => 'TCAby\\PickinteriCabinet\\Admin\\Pcab_Visitor',
   'properties' => 
      array (
        'ID' => 12,
        'first_name' => 'Don',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
        'full_name' => 'Don Smith',
        'display_name' => 'Don Smith',
        'email' => 'mail@gmail.com',
        'avatar_url' => 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocJs_EdNxyyNf-lqA1WqY8xR-q-9ZX4jOdrd2NDY3Fz9Pp7p=s96-c',
        'social_user_id' => '1144905419045954546685675134657',
        'social_app' => 'google',
      )
```

Basically, I think, there is a problem not just with this variable, its behavior is just a visible part of the iceberg - because very strange behavior after page refresh (see below)

===
Before this solution (pass class through session variable) I tried to make it just a global variable in the very first initiating file - the variable was lost, it became isset() = false.

Even before that I tried to operate with standard Wordpress mechanism - like is_user_logged_in, wp_get_user_detail etc. - similarly, when going to the second page (with the parameter) everything was lost, the user was unlogged and other mysticism.

Comment: `__PHP_Incomplete_Class` is what you get when PHP tries to restore a class instance stored in the session, but doesn't have the class definition available at this point. So you need to make sure that before the session data is restored the PHP file containing the class is already loaded.

Comment: @CBroe yes, you're right how to define __PHP_Incomplete_Class... But we talk about the same page, really! I'm using page template, started from  
<?php

/*
 * Template Name: PickinteriCabinet: Visitor Cabinet page template
 * Description: Visitor Cabinet dashboard
 */
use TCAby\PickinteriCabinet\Admin\Pcab_Visitor as Visitor;
i.e. how can I load the class before or anything else, and why the first call of the page (and I also call it now with get-param, ?mode=dashboard) has the class, but the second (?mode=settings) hasn't?

Comment: "Same page" has little to do with this. The class definition must already be loaded, when the session gets picked up again. You do not have `session_start` in your code there, so it must happen earlier.

Comment: @CBroe Looks like you were right. It doesn't explain the incomprehensible behavior of the system with other authorization options, but at least this way seems to work. I had set `session.auto_start to on`, but now after your advice I disabled it again and started using `start_session()` forcibly. It seems to work... Thanks!