# __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object even though class is included before session started

Tags: php, class, session

I have a "page" class that on it's construct includes a "shoppingCart" class, starts a session, creates a shoppingCart object, and then sets $_SESSION['shoppingCart'] to the shoppingCart object.

I still get an incomplete class when I print_r the session...

I thought this only happens when you start the session before including the class?

The code in my "page" class looks like this:

```
include ('include/shopping_cart.php');

if (session_id() == '')
    {
    session_start();
    }

if (!isset($_SESSION['shoppingCart']))
    {
    $_SESSION['shoppingCart'] = new shoppingCart;
    }
```

I obviously don't understand this...  Please help!

Comment: that's not the proper way to check if a session is running: http://php.net/session_status. And you need to show the object itself. it MUST implement serializable if you want it to properly survive being stuffed into $_SESSION.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know I needed to implement serializable in my shopping cart class!

Comment: if you weren't sticking it into $_SESSION, then it wouldn't be necessary. but sessions are serialized at shut down, and unserialized at session_start().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store an object in a session two things must happen:

1) The class must be defined before the session is started.
2) The class must implement [serializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php).