# ContextErrorException in AbstractToken.php line 70: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string

Tags: php, google-chrome, symfony

I get this error when using chrome but not in Firefox!

i have tried clearing the cache and cookies doesn't make any difference... Anyone got an idea what it is?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you tried to deserialize the object without a loaded class. First include the class (`require` or `include`) and then try.

See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441566/catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-php-incomplete-class-could-not-be-conve)

[PHP Manual: Object Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php)